# i need to display value from another db located on another server

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 websites (one coded in PHP/Mysql, the other one with some CMS platform I don't know).

My regular website (the PHP one) which functions well, displaying products (around 12,000) and stock infos for them, all from my database.

Then I have this other website (unknown code/CMS) which has *some* of the products i have on the main PHP site, and stock infos.

What I want is to display on the 2nd website, the stocks infos (how many products in stock) from the 1st PHP website. I assume I can dive a bit into the 2nd website code where the stock info is displayed and do a PHP code tweak. But I need to know which would be a good way to access my database from the 2nd website.

I assume the 2nd website is done in PHP/Mysql.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

possible suggestions

1. make some web service to fetch data from each other.
2. since both of the website are your control you have access to both database query directly.

   now the best way

it will be better to write a web service ,so that both your site are independent .

if you want to make your web service private use some authentication

Comment: i can imagine the ways possible to do this, i would have liked something more particular to the situation...maybe instead of the stock value i want to change do a Javascript function, that calls through ajax the value of my main stock, and then displays in the stock's <DIV> the value through .innerHTML ? I think this will work. what do you think ?

Comment: may be a jsonp request can help ,ajax cross domain not possible.